# How to restrict for a class list to have only child classes of a class(Probably an Abstract class)

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

For example, suppose I have an `AbstractClass` and I have a list of child classes for the `AbstractClass` called `FirstChildClass` and `SecondChildClass`. And also I have a completely `IsolatedClass`.

Now suppose the following code snippet:

```
List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<>();
classList.add(FirstChildClass.class); // this is ok
classList.add(SecondChildClass.class); // this is ok
classList.add(IsolatedClass.class); // this should not be ok
```

Simply, I want an error on the third line. Is there a way to achieve that in Java?

Comment: How about `List<Class<? extends AbstractClass>>`

Comment: Works fine, thanks. Didn't know Class has generic arguments

Answer (score 3):

If you declare your list as

```
List<Class<? extends AbstractClass>> classList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then it can only contain classes that extend `AbstractClass`.

Answer (score -1):

I think "bounded wildcards" is what you're looking for. You'd use it like this:

```
List<? extends AbstractClass> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way the list can hold only items that inherit from the AbstractClass. Same works for interfaces.

Comment: This is wrong list doesn't consist of AbstractClass objects, but java.lang.Class objects.